# Should you noidex paginated pages or use rel=next/rel=prev

Tags: seo, pagerank, google-index, canonical-url, noindex

On out site we use pagination in two places:

1) Category Pages

We have our articles segmented by category and each category has 100's of articles so we paginate at 10 articles per page. We use the following format:

(If you are on the third page)

```
<link href="http://example.com/category/categoryName/" rel="canonical"></link>
<link href="http://example.com/category/categoryName/page/2/" rel="prev"></link>
<link href="http://example.com/category/categoryName/page/4/" rel="next"></link>
```

1) Posts

Our posts are anywhere from 300 - 5000 words so we paginate after every 500 words. We use the following format:

(If you are on the second page)

```
<link href="http://example.com/year/month/postName/2/" rel="canonical"></link>
<link href="http://example.com/year/month/postName/" rel="prev"></link>
<link href="http://example.com/year/month/postName/3/" rel="next"></link>
```

In terms of "page juice dilution" and ranking, is this the best way to do it? Or should I use noindex on paginated pages instead? Should noindex be implemented only on category pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would carry on using pagination mark up on both sets of paginated pages.

Google introduced the mark up for this specific purpose, it provides a hint to Google that you would like to treat the paginated pages as a logical sequence, thus consolidating their linking properties and usually sending searchers to the first page.

If you `noindex` the paginated pages you would be missing out on those benefits. For instance say somebody linked to page 4 on your paginated page, if it was `noindexed` the weight from that backlink would be lost, but if using `rel=next/rel=prev` mark-up, this link weight would be counted to the sequence as a whole.

The two examples you posted are two of the same examples Google give in their specifications:

> News and/or publishing sites often divide a long article into several
>   shorter pages.
>
> Retail sites may divide the list of items in a large product category
>   into multiple pages.

[More info on Indicating Paginated Content from Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks. I agree about the posts. However, with categories I am still no sure. Category page X will change the content based on post updates and does it really provide much value to the user? Yoast SEO also provides an option to noindex/follow /page/2/ links and it seems to be very highly recommend. For categories, don't you want all the link juice to the main chategory page?

Comment: That's what the 'rel=next/rel=prev' does. If you noindex it, juice will be lost, with 'rel=next/rel=prev' it will count all pages as one. There isn't really a wrong answer though. You can use Noindex, rel=next, or even just leave them as is.

Comment: Will using rel=next/rel=prev prevent those pages from being indexed?

Answer (score 1):

I use both `noindex` and `rel=next/prev` on my paginated pages 2-N

noindex does not stop link juice from flowing, it flows through the noindex page. Remember that noindex only means "don't index" it does NOT mean "don't crawl".

*robots.txt* disallow will stop link juice from flowing.